# How to test that a constructor throws an exception using JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I'm making a Fraction API class, one of my constructors normalises a fraction by putting the numerator and denominator parameters in their lowest terms:

```
    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator){
    if (denominator == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot divide by zero.");
    else {
        if (denominator < 0) {
            numerator = -numerator;
            denominator = -denominator;
        }
        int gcd; // Greatest Common Divisor
        int tmpNum = numerator, tmpDen = denominator;
        // Determine greatest common divisor of numerator and denominator
        while (tmpNum != 0 && tmpDen != 0) {
            int tmp = tmpDen;
            tmpDen = tmpNum % tmpDen;
            tmpNum = tmp;
        }
        gcd = Math.abs(tmpNum + tmpDen);
        this.numerator = numerator / gcd; // Assign numerator in its lowest term
        this.denominator = denominator / gcd; // Assign denominator in its lowest term

    }
}
```

I want to test that the constructor throws an ArithmeticException when the denominator is 0. As far as I can tell JUnit 5 does not support `@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class` but uses `assertThrows()`.
My test:

```
@Test
public void testZeroDenominator(){
    Fraction f;
    assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class, f = new Fraction(2, 0));
}
```

does not work and IntelliJ says 'Fraction is not compatible with Executable'.

How can I test that the constructor throws the exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the syntax to pass *lambda* for JUnit 5's [`Executable`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Executable.html):

```
assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class, () -> new Fraction(2, 0));
```

You don't need to assign the result to `f`, because you know that the method is not going to complete.

Comment: Ahh `Executable` is an interface hence the _lambda_, only just getting to grips with interfaces. Yeah that was silly didn't think it wouldn't assign because it won't complete. Thanks!